# default behaviour for (bool) cast

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std

classes in the stl, such as unique_ptr will occasionally show examples such as:

```
// unique_ptr constructor example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {
  std::default_delete<int> d;
  std::unique_ptr<int> u1;
  std::unique_ptr<int> u2 (nullptr);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u3 (new int);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u4 (new int, d);
  std::unique_ptr<int> u5 (new int, std::default_delete<int>());
  std::unique_ptr<int> u6 (std::move(u5));
  std::unique_ptr<void> u7 (std::move(u6));
  std::unique_ptr<int> u8 (std::auto_ptr<int>(new int));

  std::cout << "u1: " << (u1?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u2: " << (u2?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u3: " << (u3?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u4: " << (u4?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u5: " << (u5?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u6: " << (u6?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u7: " << (u7?"not null":"null") << '\n';
  std::cout << "u8: " << (u8?"not null":"null") << '\n';

 *emphasized text* return 0;
}
```

The line:

```
 std::cout << "u1: " << (u1?"not null":"null") << '\n';
```

shows the unique_ptr u1 being directly cast to false if it is tracking a null pointer.

I have seen this behaviour used in other custom classes. How is this managed and what operator decides whether a direct cast to bool such as this returns true or false?

Comment: There is **no cast** in that code. There is an **implicit conversion**. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is implemented as a member conversion operator of the form `explicit operator bool() const;`. Whether it returns true or false is implemented in the logic of the class itself. For example, this class has an bool conversion operator that returns `true` if it's data member has value `42`, and `false` otherwise:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit operator bool() const { return n==42; }
  int n;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Foo f0{12};
  Foo f1{42};

  std::cout << (f0 ? "true\n" : "false\n"); 
  std::cout << (f1 ? "true\n" : "false\n"); 
}
```

Comment: +1 because you said `explicit` and the other guy didn't. C++03 doesn't have `explicit` conversions, and because of that conversion operators to `bool` caused two annoying problems. `explicit` is the solution to those, so it's really quite important.

Comment: +1 because by ignoring C++03 you did not fall in to the same pitfall other answers felt into when they provided an *unsafe* `bool` conversion.

Comment: Btw, for the love of all that is good and pure please `return i == 42;` ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop : At least it isn't `return ((bool(i==42)==true) ? true : false);`

Comment: @Steve Please refresh the page first. I was iteratively editing my answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop I can't believe I'd actually typed that. I blame it on the "legacy" code I have to deal with every day.

Answer (score 2):

```
operator bool();
```

It's a standard cast-operator to type `bool`.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
class Checked
{
    bool state;

public:
    Checked(bool _state) : state(_state) { }

    explicit operator bool() const {
        return state;
    }
};

Checked c (true);
if (c)
    cout << "true";
```

Note the `explicit` keyword. It appeared in C++11 and allows *safe* conversion of the class to bool, which happens, in short, in the logical context such as `if()`, `while()` etc. Without the `explicit`, bad things could happen, as there's an implicit conversion of `bool` to numeric types. In C++03 and older it's safer to overload `operator ! ()`, which then is tested as `if (!!c)`.

Answer (score 1):

A conversion operator is used for this functionality:

```
operator bool(){ return false; }
```

In C++11 you can also make them `explicit`

```
explicit operator bool(){ return true; }
```

Implicit conversion operators are an error prone endeavour. Consider if `unique_ptr` had an implicit conversion operator to bool, you could do nonsensical things like...

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> x;
int y = 7 + x;
```

In the above case `y` would equal `7` + (0 if x is null or 1 if x is non-null)